# Should I connect to my replica through PgBouncer?

Tags: postgresql, replication, pgbouncer

We're using a setup of one Postgresql master server and a several replicas to be able to withstand master failure. Connection to master server is made through PgBouncer. 
 
Currently the idea is that replicas would serve reads when the master is down. 
Is it a good idea to connect to replicas via PgBouncer during master failover/switchover? Should it be the same PgBouncer instance or a separate one (for fault tolerance)? 
We build a web service and a set of background jobs, database transactions are typically short-lived.
If there's an article explaining this, I would appreciate if you share a link